# ZXing Barcode Android library getting ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, barcode, zxing, classnotfoundexception

I am new to android. I am using zxing in my android project natively. I followed the steps [here](http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/). But I get get classNotFoundException for capture activity of zxing lib when I call intent calling zxing android client. Also note that when I add capture activity project as library, firstly it adds properly, then when I say apply/ok & later see again then i see red x mark for this added lib. Even the src folder of added lib is not seen in source tab. I think there is some problem while adding lib but I don't know what & how to figure it out.

Please suggest.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use `android/` as a library, and it is not a library. You are not supposed to copy this code and try to call it in your app. Instead, write your own app. Then integrate the core library (just `core/`) for decoding.

If you're new to all of this, you will probably have a lot of difficulty getting this working versus just integrating by Intent: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Comment: Ya I am new to this. And I think android/ is there android client on top of core which call camera, take a pic, decode it & return the result. I have compiled it as an library & then using it in my app. SO it is like android/ is using core & my app is using this. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Also if you know any tutorial to help me out of this please provide a link

Comment: I got it working. But now the problem is it starts the camera & does nothing forward. There is no button to catch(click) the barcode nor it automatically scans as barcode comes in front. Am I missing any procedure? Please help